# Issue importing quantecon

Tags: python, module, attributeerror

I am having an issue importing `quantecon.` I am running Python 3.6.0, but I am getting the following error message when I type

```
import quantecon
```

in the IPython terminal:

```
UntypedAttributeError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute 'iinfo' of type Module(<module 'numpy' from 
'C:\\Users\\User\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py'>)
File "..\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\quantecon\util\numba.py", line 94
[1] During: typing of get attribute at C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\quantecon\util\numba.py (94)
```

I have tried uninstall and re-install the most upgraded version of the module, but am getting the same problem. I also  have the latest version of `Pip` running. Any ideas as to what can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You might try upgrading the library `Numba`:

```
conda update numba
```

Comment: kindly consider adding more information in your answer